# ImageLoader is displaying not more than 1second

Tags: jquery

I am displaying a graph using jquery which take 6 to 7sec to load so in that time i have to display image loader. In which image loader have to display atleast for 5sec before graph loads, but its displaying only for 1sec.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    /** image loader displaying for a sec */
    $('#graph').html('<img src="images/loader.gif">');      

    $('#graph').load(function() {
       //data of graph
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#graph').html('<img src="images/loader.gif">'); // image loader displaying
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#graph').html('Loaded')
    },5000);
});
```

Comment: Rohit Batham thanks for the answer. I cannot use setTimeout function here because graph may take more than 10 to 15sec if net is slow.

Answer (score 2):

The content of #graph is being immediately replaced by the .load() method. I suggest you make a loader div such as `.graphLoader` and then load the graph data into a hidden `#graph` DIV which you then unhide `#graph` when loading is complete at the same time hiding `.graphLoader`

Here is a working Demo on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/suNK5/

CSS:

```
.graphLoader {
    display:block;
}
#graph {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="graphLoader">Graph loading...</div>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#graph").load("someGraphURL", function () {
        $('#graph').toggle();
        $('.graphLoader').toggle();
    });
});
```